# How can I create a timed interval loop in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, intervals

I have a function `search_subjects` whose results are stored in an array `subjects`. I also have a function for a setting an interval `repeat_every(secs)`. I'm trying to loop through the variables stored in the `subjects` array by using the `repeat every` interval so it searches through the array using the timed variable.

```
subjects = []
def search_subject
  subjects.each do |e|
    {e < e.length}
    repeat_every(10)
    client.search_through_subject(e)
  end
end
```

I get a `syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>`
and another `syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input`. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first error is coming from this line:

`{e < e.length}`

The curly brackets `{}` are literal notation used to create a `Hash` or a block, and it expects  something like this:

`{ :key => :value }`

It is not clear what you're trying to do, but you don't need to check whether `e` is out of bounds when using `each()`. You can just omit this line.

The second error is coming from a missing `do` keyword here:

`repeat_every(10)`

Assuming that you want to pass a block to `repeat_every()`, you can do any of these:

```
repeat_every(10) do
    client.search_through_subject(e)
end
```

or

```
repeat_every(10) { client.search_through_subject(e) }
```

The second one is generally preferred when your block is just one line.

Another word of warning. In the code that you posted, the variable `subjects` and `clients` may not be defined within your method unless you pass them in as parameters.

Comment: Ah ok, I kind of see what you mean... And to answer your confusion, I'm trying to loop through the array of subjects, not immediately, but at interval execution....in other words, pass through each stored variable at a 25 second break in between.